# Google SignInWith Redirect navigates properly on pc browsers but not on mobile browsers

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-oauth

I have a google provider signinwithredirect flow. It works perfectly on pc browsers but not on mobile browsers

I believe I used the getRedirectResult and signInWithRedirect and instructed in the documentation.
I have also added my netlify domain to my Firebase Authorized domains. I chose to use signInWithRedirect  instead of signInWithPopUp since signInWithPopUp doesn't work properly on mobile

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import SignupHead from "../assets/images/signupHead.jpg";
import { Button, IconButton, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { Facebook, FingerprintOutlined, Google } from "@mui/icons-material";
import "@fontsource/lexend";
import "@fontsource/lexend/500.css";
import {
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  getRedirectResult,
  signInWithRedirect,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { AuthContext } from "../utils/AuthContext";
import { auth, provider } from "../utils/firebaseConfig";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const Signup = () => {
  const { dispatch } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  useEffect(() => {
    getRedirectResult(auth)
      .then((result) => {
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
        const user = result.user;
        console.log(user);
        dispatch({ type: "LOGIN", payload: user.uid });

        localStorage.setItem("userCredentials", JSON.stringify(user.uid));
        localStorage.setItem("userName", JSON.stringify(user.displayName));

        navigate("/questions");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
        // ...
      });
  }, []);
  // Sign in function - Google Provider
  const handleSign = async () => {
    await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
  };
  // Saving Images to local storage

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={SignupHead} className="w-screen" />
      <div className="ml-8 mt-8">
        <Typography
          variant="body"
          sx={{
            fontFamily: "lexend",
            textTransform: "none",
          }}
        >
          Sign up / Login to continue
        </Typography>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center mt-20 space-y-4">
        <Button
          onClick={handleSign}
          className="w-5/6 h-12 "
          variant="contained"
          size="large"
          startIcon={<Google />}
          style={{
            background: "#181B24",
            borderRadius: "10vw",
            display: "flex",
            justifyItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <Typography
            variant="body"
            gutterBottom={false}
            sx={{
              fontFamily: "lexend",
              fontWeight: "100",
              textTransform: "none",
            }}
          >
            Signup with Google
          </Typography>
        </Button>
        {/* Facebook Login */}
        <Button
          className="w-5/6 h-12"
          variant="contained"
          size="large"
          startIcon={<Facebook />}
          style={{
            background: "#181B24",
            borderRadius: "10vw",
            display: "flex",
            justifyItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <Typography
            variant="body"
            gutterBottom={false}
            sx={{
              fontFamily: "lexend",
              fontWeight: "100",
              textTransform: "none",
            }}
          >
            Signup with Facebook
          </Typography>
        </Button>
        <Typography className="py-10">or</Typography>
        <div
          className="flex flex-col items-center"
          style={{
            borderRadius: "50%",
            width: "10vw",
            backgroundColor: "#14151D",
          }}
        >
          <IconButton size="large" color="secondary">
            <FingerprintOutlined />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <div className="my-8">
          <Typography>Log in with fingerprint sensor </Typography>
        </div>
        <div className="absolute bottom-0 text-center">
          <Typography>
            By continuing, you are agreeing to Haven’s terms and policies
          </Typography>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

RequireAuth.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const RequireAuth = ({ children }) => {
  const userCredentials = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userCredentials"));
  return <div>{userCredentials ? children : <Navigate to="/signup" />}</div>;
};
```